# Display all row instead of 3 row

Tags: material-ui, react-tsx

Goal:
Display all row in the in table at the same time.

Problem:
It display only 3 row at the same time in the table.
I would like to display all row at the same time without any limitation.

It doesn't work to use "height: '100%'"

Any idea?

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mkd4dw?file=/demo.tsx

Thank you!

---

demo.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Rating from '@mui/material/Rating';
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridRenderCellParams,
  GridColDef,
  useGridApiContext,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

function renderRating(params: GridRenderCellParams<number>) {
  return <Rating readOnly value={params.value} />;
}

function RatingEditInputCell(props: GridRenderCellParams<number>) {
  const { id, value, field } = props;
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number | null) => {
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: newValue });
  };

  const handleRef = (element: HTMLSpanElement) => {
    if (element) {
      const input = element.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(
        `input[value="${value}"]`,
      );
      input?.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', pr: 2 }}>
      <Rating
        ref={handleRef}
        name="rating"
        precision={1}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

const renderRatingEditInputCell: GridColDef['renderCell'] = (params) => {
  return <RatingEditInputCell {...params} />;
};

export default function CustomEditComponent() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 250, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const columns = [
  {
    field: 'places',
    headerName: 'Places',
    width: 120,
  },
  {
    field: 'rating',
    headerName: 'Rating',
    renderCell: renderRating,
    renderEditCell: renderRatingEditInputCell,
    editable: true,
    width: 180,
    type: 'number',
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, places: 'Barcelona', rating: 5 },
  { id: 2, places: 'Rio de Janeiro', rating: 4 },
  { id: 3, places: 'London', rating: 3 },
  { id: 4, places: 'New York', rating: 2 },
];
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `autoHeight` prop supported by the `<DataGrid />` component, update your DataGrid component usage to this:

```
<DataGrid
  autoHeight
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
/>
```

Reference: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/layout/#auto-height